# Resizing UITextView with Pan Gesture

Tags: ios, swift

I created a custom `UIView` class. The `UIView` has a subview that is a `UITextView`. 
I then added a mini `UIView` at the right bottom corner of the `UITextView` as its subview. I added a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the mini `UIView` so that it would follow my finger around, and the `UITextView` would resize based on the pan movement.

Below is my handler for the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, however my implementation is not working. The `UITextView` disappears when the gesture is recognized. Note that `self` in the function below is referring to the main `UIView`.

```
@objc func handleFramePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    var originalFrame: CGRect = textView.frame

    if recognizer.state == .began {
        originalFrame = textView.frame

    } else if recognizer.state == .changed {
        let horizontalChange = recognizer.translation(in: self).x
        let verticalChange = recognizer.translation(in: self).y

        let newFrame = CGRect(x: originalFrame.origin.x, y: originalFrame.origin.y, width: originalFrame.width + horizontalChange, height: originalFrame.height + verticalChange)

        textView.frame = newFrame
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the view is disappearing because you changing the width and height based on 1:1 ratio with the pan change, u can try factoring the pan change and see if that helps.

Comment: @OverD what factoring are you referring too? Wouldn't `recognizer.translation(in: self)` return a `CGPoint` that is universal?

Comment: a pan recognizer looks for the beginning of translational movement and continues to report movement in any direction over time. So what I would try to do is divid the translation by 10 or even more and see if that gets your desired effect.